# Why are shutter speed and ISO sometimes shown in strange fractions?

Tags: dslr, shutter-speed, iso

Sometimes, browsing 500px or any other photo site that holds EXIF info, I see some weird shutter and ISO tagging.

Some EXIF says that the photo was taken with 80000 or 160000 ISO. Is it relevant to 800 and 1600 ISO? I've never seen ISO going above 25600.
Also, some photos save shutter speed in:
2/100 or 10/1000. How is it relevant to e.g. 1/320?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are totally right with your assumption of the ISO it would indeed by ISO 1600 and 800.

2/100 if you use the standard laws of mathematics and fractions this would become 1/50. Hence 2/100 = 1/50, 10/1000 = 1/100 and so on.

This incorrect EXIF data can be caused by the processing of the image. In some cases programs will alter the EXIF to make it compatible.

You might also find malfunctioning EXIF batch scripts could also be a contribute.